# How to Use $.ajax? when I use Its not hitting my controller Action

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Can any body help me out.

I have this code

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<script type="text/javascript">


    function GOTO() {
        var datastring = "id=2";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/Index",
            dataType: "json",
            data: datastring,
            success: function (json) { Complete(json.result); },
            error: function (request, status, error) {
                //alert("an error occurred: " + error);
                alert("Error saving data. Please contact support.");
            }
        });
    }

    function Complete(result) {
        if (result == "success") {
            alert("Success");  
        }
        else {
            alert("Failed");
        }
    }
</script>

 <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="JavaScript:GOTO()" />

</asp:Content>
```

and My Controller Code is this

```
[HttpPost]
public System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult Index(string datastring)
{
   return Json(new { foo = "bar", baz = "Blech" });
}
```

But it never hits my controller at all, is that Something I am doing wrong in my View?

thanks

Comment: Do you get an error in the JavaScript console when you click the button?

Comment: if it's not hitting the server side, you have an error on the client side, tools like Firebug should help you quickly identify those

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function Complete(result) {
    if (result == "success") {
        altert("Success");
       // ^ beware!
```

You have a syntax error in your code.

Moreover, you don't need to specify the `JavaScript:` protocol in the `onclick` attribute, you're merely defining a label at that place. Even better, don't assign event listeners in HTML attributes at all, but use unobtrusive JavaScript, including a fallback for the rare case when JavaScript is unavailable.

**Update:** if you get the "`$.ajax` is undefined" error, you probably didn't include jQuery in your page. Add

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/jquery-X.X.X.js"></script>
```

To your page *above* the `script` element that uses `$.ajax` (or any other jQuery function).

Comment: Thanks Marcel, even I changed that but its not working for me.. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try passing the `data` like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Home/Index",
    dataType: "json",
    data: { datastring: 'foo bar' },
    success: function (json) { Complete(json.result); },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        alert("Error saving data. Please contact support.");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Darin, I tried this but no luck I am getting error $.ajax is not defined.thanks

Comment: @user300485, the fact that you are getting a `$.ajax is undefined` error is something that you should have mentioned in your question as then the answer would have been straightforward. This being said, still I would recommend you passing parameters as I showed in my answer as this will take care of properly url encoding them.

Answer (score 2):

it could be down to what data you are passing in. Your method expects a parameter called datastring but you are passing in 'id=2'.

Comment: I changed that to int id Andy but still its not hitting the controler? thanks